# Silverlight blank page but only from one machine

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

A silverlight application is deployed to IIS. I can access it from two different machines. However, a user from another machine only sees blank page.

I do not suspect mime types and other IIS/server issues because it works fine except for this user.

The user can access other Silverlight apps, on same server.

What can be the problem on the client's machine?

UPD: user can't access .xap file directly, restricted access.
UPD: looks to be a proxy in the middle.

Comment: have you tried using different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, can't delete my own post? Well, this looks to be network problem with proxy.

Comment: See this: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82065/how-can-i-delete-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

It seems a cross-domain issue, and normally an unhandled exception causes the Silverlight content to go blank, even-though if you right-click you would get `Silverlight` menu action.